# SQL: Eliminating duplicates with specific conditions

Tags: sql, impala

I have a SQL database that SOMETIMES has duplicate values, but only in one column (phone number).  If there is a duplicate, the other attributes in the same row are filled in with NULL.  In other cases, the phone number is not duplicated, but still has NULL values in the rows.  Ex:

| first_name | last_name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | smith | 123-456-7890 |
| NULL | NULL | 123-456-7890 |
| NULL | NULL | 456-789-1011 |
| carry | smith | 121-314-1516 |

I'm trying to write a query that eliminates cases where the phone number is duplicated and the other values in the row are NULL, to get:

| first_name | last_name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | smith | 123-456-7890 |
| NULL | NULL | 456-789-1011 |
| carry | smith | 121-314-1516 |

Any ideas?

Comment: you could just select max for first_name, last_name and group by phone_number... though  if you have 3 records with the same phone number you will mix/match data.  Such as if Dana Smith and Don Smith share a phone number (hey in my example they are married) don would be the only one listed....

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this you probably want a NOT EXISTS clause.  This does a lookup for each row in the table, to see if there are any other records with the same phone number and populated name fields.

```
select
    first_name,
    last_name,
    phone_number
from
    phone_numbers pn
where
    not exists (
        select 1
        from phone_numbers pn2
        where pn2.phone_number = pn.phone_number
        and pn.first_name is not null
        and pn.last_name is not null
    )
```

Although I'm not sure it's perfect.  If there is a case where two records have the same phone number and both have NULL names then neither would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

One way, might be to use a subquery to identify the phone_numbers only once.. and then outer join to the records you want without nulls. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 (SELECT phone_number AS root_phone_number
  FROM table
  GROUP BY phone_number
 ) AS phonenumbers
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE first_name IS NOT NULL
 ) as notnulls
ON phonenumbers.phone_number = notnulls.phone_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fastest way to do it, left join to the items you want to remove and then add a where clause for null results for the join.  Every row that meets the join requirements WILL NOT be in the results.

I call this an Exclusionary Left Join.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableyoudidnotname main
LEFT JOIN tableyoudidnotname sub on 
               main.phone_number = sub.phone_number 
           and sub.first_name is null 
           and sub.last_name is null
WHERE sub.phone_number is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use cte for it. Here's the code that does it.

```
    with cte as (
    select phone_number from phone_numbers 
    group by phone_number
    having count(*) > 1
)

delete phone_numbers
where phone_number in (select phone_number from cte)
and first_name is null and last_name is null
```